# List of last used files in Windows 11 start menu available?

Tags: windows-11, start-menu

If I dock an app onto the taskbar, or launch it. I can see the recent used files, when I click on the icon with the right mouse.

In the Windows 11 start menu I see only some options, when I right click on an application icon.

Is this correct, or just a missing feature?

Comment: If I dock an app onto the taskbar, or launch it. I can see the recent used files,   ...  Depends on the App but roughly normal.   ..........   In the Windows 11 start menu I see only some options,   ....  This is related more to the app than to files.   So overall what you see is norma.

Answer (score 0):

The option to show jump-lists is by default disabled in Windows 11.

To show jump-lists :

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Start*
- Turn on the option of
  "Show recently opened items in Start, Jump Lists, and File Explorer".

The effect is immediate.

Comment: That option you describe is ON by default - at least in Windows 11 23H2.   I checked that before I commented.

Comment: Of course (and I should have mentioned) the OP should check this point.

Comment: @John: This option was off for me after upgrading to Windows 11.

Comment: It may have been an upgrade issue. The systems I checked were new systems with Windows 11 Preloaded. That may be the reason.

Comment: This option is on. But even than I don't see filenames in the App Lists.

Comment: It works for me, very strange. Try running DISM/SFC. Is Windows fully updated?

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer for out-of-the-box Windows 11, but maybe this is a workaround for you, if you don't find a solution:
I use OpenShell Menu, which is an extension that lets you configure the Windows start menu to look e.g. like older versions of Windows. In this modified start menu, I have a list of recent files.